# what wrong with CPHPAuthmanger?

Tags: php, yii

I am using CPHPAuthmanager for RBAC. I don't know what's wrong in my code? why it doesn't assign roles except normal whenever someone logs in?

//protected/config/app.php

```
<?php
  return array(
'userTypes' => array(
    'normal' => 0,
    'admin' => 1,
    'student' => 2,
    'teacher' => 3

),
'userTypesArray' => array(
    0 => 'normal',
    1 => 'admin',
    2 => 'student',
    3 => 'teacher'
),
    );
?>
```

//protected/data/auth.php

```
<?php
  return array(
'admin' => array(
        'type' => 2,
        'description' => '',
        'bizRule' => NULL,
        'data' => NULL
    ),

'student' => array(
        'type' => 2,
        'description' => '',
        'bizRule' => NULL,
        'data' => NULL
    ),

'teacher' => array(
        'type' => 2,
        'description' => '',
        'bizRule' => NULL,
        'data' => NULL
    ),

'normal' => array(
        'type' => 2,
        'description' => '',
        'bizRule' => NULL,
        'data' => NULL
    )
 );

?>
```

//protected/components/UserIdentity.php

```
if(count($users) == 0)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    elseif ($users[0]->password!==$this->password)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
        Yii::app()->authManager->clearAuthAssignments();
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        $this->setState('rol', $users[0]->type);
        if($users[0]->type == Yii::app()->params['app']['userTypes']['admin'])
            Yii::app()->authManager->assign('admin', $users[0]->UId);
        elseif($users[0]->type == Yii::app()->params['app']['userTypes']['student'])
            Yii::app()->authManager->assign('student', $users[0]->UId);
        elseif($users[0]->type == Yii::app()->params['app']['userTypes']['teacher'])
            Yii::app()->authManager->assign('teacher', $users[0]->UId);
        else
        {
            Yii::app()->authManager->assign('normal', $users[0]->UId);
        }
        Yii::app()->authManager->save();
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
```

// config/main

```
$auth=Yii::app()->authManager;

$bizRule='return !Yii::app()->user->isGuest;';

$auth->createRole('normal', 'Normal User', $bizRule);

$bizRule='return (isset(Yii::app()->user->rol))? (Yii::app()->user->rol === "admin") : false;';
$auth->createRole('admin', 'System Admin', $bizRule);

$bizRule='return (isset(Yii::app()->user->rol))? (Yii::app()->user->rol === "student") : false;';
$auth->createRole('student', 'Student', $bizRule);

$bizRule='return (isset(Yii::app()->user->rol))? (Yii::app()->user->rol === "teacher") : false;';
$auth->createRole('teacher', 'Teacher', $bizRule);
```

//controllers/somecontroller

```
public function accessRules()
{
return array(
            array('allow', 
            'actions'=>array('index', 'view', 'create', 'update', 'admin','delete'),
            'roles'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

Please help me, thanks in advance. :)

Comment: At a minimum, you need to call save() on the authManager to save any assignments or other changes. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPhpAuthManager#save-detail

Comment: I 've tried it. It only saves normal role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config/main components section define like this.

```
'authManager' =>array(
   ...
   'defaultRoles' => array('normal', 'admin', 'student', 'teacher'),
),
```

Then create roles like this with bizrules

```
$auth=Yii::app()->authManager;

$bizRule='return !Yii::app()->user->isGuest;';
$auth->createRole('normal', 'Normal User', $bizRule);

$bizRule='return (isset(Yii::app()->user->rol))? (Yii::app()->user->rol === "admin") : false;';
$auth->createRole('admin', 'System Admin', $bizRule);

$bizRule='return (isset(Yii::app()->user->rol))? (Yii::app()->user->rol === "student") : false;';
$auth->createRole('student', 'Student', $bizRule);

$bizRule='return (isset(Yii::app()->user->rol))? (Yii::app()->user->rol === "teacher") : false;';
$auth->createRole('teacher', 'Teacher', $bizRule);

$auth->save();
```

take care I didnt use 'role' I use 'rol' instead we will define in UserIdentity now. Just after you take the logged user data in UserIdentity, just set rol state to user object with this code:

```
$this->setState('rol', $user->type); //can be 'normal', 'admin', 'student', 'teacher'
```

Comment: where to define these roles?

Comment: you can create an action and run that 1 time for creating biz rules and roles with given codes. It will create the config depends on your authManager component on the config/main.php. [look to the bottom of this title](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#defining-authorization-hierarchy)